# How to use json-ld in VisualStudio project

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json-ld

The MVC project is written is written in VisualStudio 2013,
I'm trying to add  the following snippet

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Vehicle",
...
}
```

I've also referenced json-ld.net in the solution
The problem is, the '@' symbol causes VS2013 to report an error and it won't run on IIS7.5.  So I obviously am missing something.  Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

After posting above, I tried one last trick and changed it accordingly,  it compiles now with out issue and displays without error.

Trick is to escape "@".

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@@type": "Vehicle",
```